# How can I get pipenv to not ignore version numbers with using --dev?

Tags: python, pipenv

When I set a specific version for a package in my `Pipfile` and use `pipenv install` that specific version is installed.  However, when I use `pipenv install --dev` and one of the dev packages requires that first package (regardless of version) my specified version number isn't respected.

An example is probably best:

```
$ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 9.0.3

$ pipenv --python 3
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 to create virtualenv…
⠋Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/scratch-kl-E6MqG/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/scratch-kl-E6MqG/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: /home/daniel/.local/share/virtualenvs/scratch-kl-E6MqG

$ pipenv shell

$ pip freeze

$ pipenv install
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (53ac0c)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 2/2 — 00:00:02

$ pip freeze
Django==1.11.9
pytz==2017.3

$ pipenv install --dev
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (53ac0c)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 6/6 — 00:00:04

$ pip freeze
Django==2.0.1
django-debug-toolbar==1.9.1
pytz==2017.3
sqlparse==0.2.4

$ cat Pipfile
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[packages]

django = "<2.0,>=1.11"


[dev-packages]

django-debug-toolbar = "*"
```

It's important to note that the requirements on `django-debug-toolbar` are [`>=1.11`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/setup.py#L21), so there's no need to upgrade the `Django` package, and yet, that's exactly what's happening.

Is this a bug, or something I've done wrong?

Comment: What is the version of pipenv are you using?

Comment: 9.0.3, running on Arch if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1220) (now fixed), so if someone else runs into this, now you know where to look :-)